Css problem when converting pdftohtml then html to pdf with wkhtmltopdf
Css problem when converting pdftohtml then html to pdf with wkhtmltopdf.
I'm trying to convert a pdf to html, then translate the html and finally convert it back to PDF with wkhtmltopdf for my website https://www.transladocs.com. The problem appeared immediately when I converted it to HTML with the command pdftohtml -c -s documents/fss4.pdf fss4-original.html. The writing became smaller, the content was placed on the left and other problems appeared.
Here's an image link to give you an idea of what happened.
https://ibb.co/9HqYVRC
After a long period of debugging, I finally solved these problems by adding these CSS codes, removing the bgcolor=”#A0A0A0 attribute in the body and removing the CSS codes in the style attribute in “id=”page1-div“” and id=”page2-div“ which allowed me to display the HTML a little more appropriately in my browser.
#page-container {
        background-color: #9e9e9e;
        background-image: url(https://www.translatedocs.bloggors.com/assets/files/background.svg);
        -webkit-transition: left 500ms;
        transition: left 500ms;
        margin-top: -25px;
    }

    .pf {
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #333;
        border-collapse: separate;
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 13px auto;
        border: 0;
        width:1024.000000px;
        height:1455.411765px;
        margin-bottom: -10px;
    }

Next, I translated my HTML correctly. After that, I tried to convert my HTML to pdf with this command
wkhtmltopdf fss4-html-translated.html fss4-html-translated.pdf
it was converted but not completely to PDF.
Here's the link to the image result to give you an idea.
https://ibb.co/1vHL54F
I think it's a CSS problem. I'd like to know if, by submitting the original HTML file and the translated HTML file, you could take a look at it so that I can improve it and produce an excellent result in the same way as the original PDF? Could you help? Here's the github link where you'll find the original PDF, the translated PDF, the original HTML and the translated HTML. I don't want you to use this kind of command pdf2htmlEX --fit-width 1024 --space-as-offset 1 abc.pdf abc.html to keep exactly the same layout, because the translation will be very difficult to do and it's almost impossible. However, I want you to give me a solution with this instead pdftohtml -c -s documents/fss4.pdf fss4-original.html
Any help you can give me will be greatly appreciated.

PDF is generally a "final" or "export" format. Programs do their work in their native format and then a one-off is created for PDF. That format was never really intended to have another "next step", beyond archiving and printing. The fact that some really smart people made tools to convert PDF to HTML is awesome, but these are really meant for text extraction purposes, although the CSS they produce has really come a long way too. But then asking to round-trip back to PDF and have it look the same, especially for a very tight PDF as you are using, is asking for a lot.

If you really want to achieve success in this, the best way that I can think to attack this is page-by-page. Export page as individual files, convert to HTML, do your work, and convert back to PDF. PDF and HTML are very conflicting in that the former has "pages", each of which can be different sizes, whereas the latter is one giant "page". There's media directives, sure, but you will still debug this in an infinite page. Keeping the model of one-page-to-one-page might help you.

@Chris Haas Thanks for the explanation. I wanted to tell you that this is how I started working on it page by page. And despite everything, I got this css problem. Please! Can you see the repository on Github so you can see the files? It was worse before... It's after a lot of time debugging my css code and testing it many times with the wkhtmltopdf command that I can get it to this level. But now I'm totally blocked at this level and I don't know what to do about it. Can you please look at the css codes for me?

Unfortunately I am unable to help you. Even if a paying client asked for this, I would tell them it would be easier to just re-layout the original form in a tool like InDesign or Illustrator and change the text there. Possibly just Acrobat Pro (whatever it is called these days). If you are looking for more than just this form, some universal solution, that's an even bigger ask.

@Chris Haas Ah ok I understand. I wanted to use it in my PHP code to translate PDFs the way I wanted.

@Kj Thank you for the translation of this PDF. I would like to tell you that I used to use the translation of this PDF in my site with the Google api. But it has become too expensive and I don't know how I can use it 100% free. Do you have any idea how I can use it for free to translate the PDF?

Even if I add other PDFs, CSS management is still poorly managed?

According to setasign.com , it clearly mentioned that my PDF is not an xfa https://ibb.co/tLq0Ynx .

Which Adobe products do you recommend? Can you give me one that is 100% free?

You know, I'd rather use it in my https://www.transladocs.com site. I'm wondering if there isn't a command in the terminal or something in PHP to use Adobe Acrobat DC? Is it possible to use it with PHP?

The only easy fix here is to reduce the font size so that the text fits within the original bounds. Otherwise you will need to completely recreate the layout as @ChrisHaas mentioned.
